# Ionic icons not aligned

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework for a project. I changed the default **font icons** to **images** and I can't align the icon at the vertical position. See image below:

[image: Icon not aligned]

The style.css:

```
.icon-requests, .icon-alerts, .icon-companies, .icon-messages, .icon-profile {
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -0.1em;
}
.icon-requests {
    background-image: url("../img/requests.png");
}

.icon-alerts {
    background-image: url("../img/alerts.png");
}

.icon-companies {
    background-image: url("../img/companies.png");
}

.icon-messages {
    background-image: url("../img/messages.png");
}

.icon-profile {
    background-image: url("../img/profile.png");
}
```

And the tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only">


    <ion-tab icon="icon icon-requests" href="#/tab/requests">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-requests"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="icon-alerts" href="#/tab/alerts">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-alerts"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="icon-companies" href="#/tab/companies">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-companies"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="icon-messages" href="#/tab/messages">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-messages"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="icon-profile" href="#/tab/profile">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Any ideas of how can I fix this? I already tried to "copy" the class icon, the .ion class, but without success.

Just an update, as suggested by @dippas I tried to remove the vertical-align: top and put some "pixels" at the background-position. The problem is: I think there is something limiting the size of the icons or another div above "covering" the image. See below for an update:

[image: The div? bug.]

Comment: since I don't have a fiddle to work with, a couple a things you should try: remove `vertical-align: top;` and/or instead of this:  `background-position: center center;`try something like: `background-position: 0 5px;`

Comment: sorry mis understood i will check and let you know, how to make it proper

Comment: use sprite and align it properly and use positioning to place it

Comment: @dippas I tried, see the update above. It looks like something is "covering" the image. I'll try to put a z-index, but I don't know if it will work.

Comment: You don't have a width or height on the containers, so see if that helps. Also see if it helps to change their display to inline-block or similar.

Comment: @ralph.m It's allowed to use width or height on Ionic? Since it's iPhone and the screen can change (and also the width).

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Sprite is a good thing, but the problem isn't about image loading size, it's about positioning haha. Maybe there is a div "above" everything, but I don't know .

Comment: I am using this code [Icon-only Tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icon-only-tabs).

Comment: @ starkbr - i am not saying about image loading size, in sprite you can align the images properly and in css you can position it, there will be no confusion

Comment: have you tried setting up the height?

Comment: There is something limiting the height. But you are correct, @dippas. Just changed the height to 48px and it worked haha. Thanks.

Comment: You need me to give an answer then?

Comment: @dippas I think so. :)

Comment: I think you need to write an answer below so I can give the "plus" to you haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have a fiddle to work with, a couple a things you should try:

- **remove** `vertical-align: top;`

  and/or:
- **change** this: `background-position: center center;` to
  something like: `background-position: 0 5px;`

because these solutions above did quite work (based on your question's update) , you should do this:

- **set** `height` in this line: *`.icon-requests, .icon-alerts,
  .icon-companies, .icon-messages, .icon-profile`*

with that it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```css
.tabs .tab-item .icon.mcfly {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/home.png');
    background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<ion-tab icon="icon icon-home" href="#/tab/requests" icon-on="mcfly" icon-off="mcfly">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here's how I solved it. 
The `<ion-tabs>` element used to look like this

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
```

And each tab inside it had these attributes

```
<ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
   <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

In this case it will show an icon and a title. You can remove `title="Status"` if you only want the icon to be displayed. In order to make sure it's aligned vertically, change the class attribute in `<ion-tabs>` from `class="tabs-icon-top"` to `class="tabs-icon-only"` which will solve the problem automatically.

Read more about it here http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icon-only-tabs